# After setting layout constant for label it stops working

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a table view with automaticDimension for height and 2 cells.
One cell has a read more button, which updates the layout constraint constant for a label (as IBOutlet). It works fine and the cell height updates depending on the label height, but when I try to update the layout constraint first time on cellForRowAt method delegate it works, but after that it stops working from the read more button (and the layout constraint outlet doesn't become nil).

```
    if cellType == .movie {
        let movieCell = cell as! MovieDescriptionCell
        movieCell.updateCellWith(movie: selectedMovie!)
        movieCell.infoLabelHeight.constant = 200. ***(here is the problem, if I don't have this the read more button works)***
        movieCell.readMorePressedBlock = { [weak self] (tag) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(70), execute: {
                strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    } 


@IBOutlet var infoLabelHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!


  @IBAction func onReadMoreButton(button: UIButton) {
    self.readMoreState = !self.readMoreState
    setReadMoreImageFor(state: readMoreState)

    let infoText = self.infoLabel.text
    let expectedHeight = infoText?.height(withConstrainedWidth: infoLabelWidth.constant, font: self.infoTextFont) ?? self.infoDefaultHeight

    self.infoLabelHeight.constant = self.readMoreState ? expectedHeight : self.infoDefaultHeight

    readMorePressedBlock?(button.tag)
}
```

How can I make this work? If I delete the line "movieCell.infoLabelHeight.constant = 200" the read more button works, but I need to set the constant at the beginning too.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use this whenever you change a constraints   cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, if I set the layout constraint in awakeFromNib method the read more button works (the possibility to change the constraint again)

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.infoLabelHeight.constant = 200
}
```